# is there any hotkey for empathy?

Tags: empathy, plugins

is there any hotkey for empathy? plugins is also ok? I want open a message with shortcut just like press F4,I can do that in pidgin, but I prefer empathy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first go to the **Settings** -> **Keyboard Settings**

---

go to **Custom Shortcuts**
[image: first]

---

click on  <kbd>+</kbd>
[image: second]

---

type in `Name`: **Empathy** and `Command` **empathy**
[image: third]

---

and add shortcut as <kbd>F4</kbd>
[image: fourth]

Comment: @lan.alps your'e welcome!